# How to write "K extends keyof T" in a generic class and use K then

Tags: typescript, generics, web

I want to create a class, which gets an object as type parameter and then uses the type as a type of a property in that class, so that I can only set and get values, if that key exists in that object.

I create an interface, lets call it IStorage. A class Storage should implement iStorage and store values based on if the key exists in the given object.

```
interface iStorage<T, K extends keyof T> {
    getField(k: K): T[K];

    setField(k: K, v: string | number | object): T[K];

    render(): void;
}

class Storage<T, K extends keyof T> implements iStorage<T, K> {
    private fields: { [key: K]: string | number | object };

    public getField(k: K): T[k] {
        return this.fields[k];
    }

    public setField(k: K, v: string | number | object): T[k] {
        return (this.fields[k] = v);
    }
}


let storage = new Storage<{name: string, type: number}>();
```

I want fields in Storage to match the the generic defintion (I think T[K]), but typescript says that key must be of type string or number, so this is not working as expected. In my interface I would like to say, that the second parameter of setFormField is also T[K].
I also think, that my type definition is repetitive. Typescript wants me to give a seconds argument too, which makes sense to me, but I don't want to write K extends keyof T everytime on a function, nor could I then use it as a property type.

Tried quiet a lot, but couldn't get it to work.. I'm a bit lost actually, since I'm trying this for several hours now. Never had to do with generics before, so please be gentle on me. :D

Hope someone could give me a helping hand.

Comment: So, do you mostly want something like `Storage<T>` to act like a wrapper around a single object of type `T` where you can get and set fields via method instead of dot access?  I'm trying to understand what you want the `K` in `Storage<T, K>` to be doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure about your use case, but I'd be inclined to alter your code to something like this:

```
interface IStorage<T extends object> {
  getField<K extends keyof T>(k: K): T[K];
  setField<K extends keyof T>(k: K, v: T[K]): T[K];
  render(): void;
}

class Storage<T extends object> implements IStorage<T> {
  constructor(private fields: T) { }
  render() { }

  public getField<K extends keyof T>(k: K) {
    return this.fields[k];
  }

  public setField<K extends keyof T>(k: K, v: T[K]): T[K] {
    return (this.fields[k] = v);
  }
}

let storage = new Storage({ name: "str", type: 123 });
const str = storage.getField("name");
const num = storage.setField("type", 456);
```

[Playground link](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBZAngOXBAynRSA3gFBJICWwALhAE4BmCyAkjlQPa0gDmEAPABUkEAB41gAEyhJ2AIwBWEeFQB8RUmSS8qAMXIQANhL4BpYWIiTpAawhp29JAJUAKawC4kJgJSeBAbRMAXQBuDTIoCF19I1NzcSkkW3tHZzdPEwAaJAA3P0Cg3ycCsM0kWksJOhcinPZyCVKkAF9iDXgDEChpNk4efiFRBOk5RWU1cjAYAwhIamlWDi5ePgAFEFoqchADQRU1EjL4dmAoKloAV2VOFxhachyQGiR6GKlPdc3t3ecAXkJmt4iK0yhVJNUgQC2mUYBdZAZyPAtFE9IZjGYhpUbHYHE5XB4vJDwpoKlQLrRgEgqAALchQAB0rzRUH81lCxNaxNh8MRSEi0TRcUxViSONS+Iy2TyxWCRQCwXUZTIpPJlJcNLpjLeLLZSF+uW8TTIIJa0KQMyofKW-T1SGAEAA7khessIC5CHbsJ4AERnWje7JUNAwCCeACMACYAMwtQ3tE5nK20W1nPq8enaVFGFze0CQb1xsjHU6W4AXMAp63p-lZiQ5oMhgNIAAsAFYAGxx1pAA)

Here the `IStorage` interface only depends on the type `T` of the object, and the individual `getField()` and `setField()` methods are themselves generic functions which can act on any property key `K` from `keyof T`.  The generic type parameter `K` does not appear on the interface itself.

I've changed the implementation of `Storage` to match.  Note that I've made the constructor take a value of type `T` which is stored as a private member.  If you don't want to have to pass in an initial value, then you will have to restrict `T` to a type with all optional properties (that is, using something like `Partial<T>` instead of just `T`.)

And you can see from the code above (or in the playground link) that the IntelliSense is how you want it... calling `getField("name")` is known to return a value of type `string`.

Okay, hope that helps you.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, this is what I wanted (playground)! :) After looking a while at this (and testing), its quiet logical, but still, very confusing to me. Definitly need to work more with generics to properly understand how to implement them. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your key type `[key: K]` cannot be handled by Typescript. What would two objects as keys be like? When are they considered equal? Hence the type of Records/Dictionary keys **must** be either string, number or symbol and nothing else.

You *might* be able to mimick what you're attempting by using an array of tuples such as `Array<[KeyType, ValueType]>` and filter by first element of the tuples.